# Spring Boot Swagger annotations for supporting API KEYs on AWS API Gateway

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to setup an AWS API Gateway that requires an API KEY in the header of any request. I setup swagger to generate the json definition and AWS imports it perfectly fine. However when I try to add the API KEY Security definition, Amazon rejects my swagger api doc with this error:

`Your API was not imported due to errors in the Swagger file.
API Key security definition 'api_key' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring.`

I assume i'm doing it wrong...so i've tried several variations along these lines.

given a spring boot config created using springfox thusly:

```
 @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {

    List<ApiKey> securitySchemes = new ArrayList<>();
    ApiKey apiKey = new ApiKey("apiKey", "api_key", "header");
    list.add(apiKey);
    //the above is probably where i'm missing something

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(securitySchemes)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/swaggertest"))
                .build();
    }
```

and the above api defined like so:

```
@RestController
public class SwaggerTestController {

      @ApiOperation(notes = "my notes", value = "test", nickname = "testNickname",
                tags = {"tests"}, authorizations = {@Authorization(value="api_key")} )
        @ApiResponses({
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Nice!", response = Swag.class)
        })
        @RequestMapping(value = "/api/swaggertest", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<Swag> getSwag() throws Exception {


                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new Swag());

        }
    }
```

When i run my app the api-docs produce (i remove some sections to keep it smaller):

```
{
swagger: "2.0",

host: "localhost:4014",
basePath: "/",
tags: [
{
    name: "swagger-test-controller",
    description: "Swagger Test Controller"
}
],
paths: {
    /api/swaggertest: {
get: {
    tags: [
    "tests"
],
summary: "test",
description: "my notes",
operationId: "testNickname",
consumes: [
    "application/json"
],
produces: [
    "application/json"
],
responses: {
    200: {
    description: "Nice!",
    schema: {
        $ref: "#/definitions/Swag"
    }
    }
   },
    security: [
    {
    api_key: [ ]
    }
    ]
    }
   }
},
securityDefinitions: {
    api_key: {
    type: "apiKey",
    name: "api_key",
    in: "header"
}
},
definitions: {
    Swag: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
    foo: {
        type: "string"
}
```

}
  }
}

if anyone can help point me to how to add api key support to this, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security definition should look like this, referencing `<any_name>` in your method security.

```
"<any_name>" : {
  "type" : "apiKey",
  "name" : "x-api-key",
  "in" : "header"
},
```

Comment: this is exactly correct, thanks.  the springfox sdk with a ApiKey defined as ```ApiKey apiKey = new ApiKey("any_name", "x-api-key", "header");``` doesn't produce this result - modifying the json manually before uploading it fixed it -  it results in ```any_name: {
type: "apiKey",
name: "any_name",
in: "header"
}``` i'll check in with the springfox guys.